# can't figure out the Y position for a <p> tag in a flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm stuck at the following code, trying to get my tooltips to show up in the correct Y position..

i've tried all the experimentation options that i could think of..

elements show the same exact X and Y .offset() and .position() despite being in a relative flow.

The fact that the entire thing is in a flexbox environment could have something to do with it, but i'm new to flexbox and don't fully understand it yet :(

https://jsfiddle.net/rveerman/m5ht734w/3/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    
    <title>zoned.at url link shortener</title>
    
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@300&family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/tooltipster-master/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tooltipster-master/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    <link href="content.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body theme="light">
    <img id="btnThemeSwitch" src="/nicerapp/siteMedia/btnThemeSwitch_icon.png" class="tooltip" title="Switch between light and dark theme" alt="Switch between light and dark theme" tooltipTheme="mainTooltipTheme" onclick="nas.themeSwitch()"/>
    <form id="siteSettings" action="/" method="POST" style="display:none;">
        <select id="siteTheme" name="siteTheme" form="siteSettings" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <optgroup>
            <option value="dark" >Dark</option>
            <option value="light" >Light</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </form>    

    <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item">
                <div class="flex-title">
            <h1>zoned.at url link shortener</h1>
            <div class="H2" colspan="3">Pricing</div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
                <div class="offer">
                    <div class="pricingTitle">
                        <h3>Free &amp; Anonymous</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="conditions">
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipLinks">
                            <span>Links</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipRedirects">
                            <span>Redirects</span>
                            <span>one-hundred-thousand (max, per month)<br/>(optionally, you'll be notified per e-mail when you risk losing clicks)</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipChange">
                            <span>Change the url redirected</span>
                            <span>not possible</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipCustom">
                            <span>Custom links / branding</span>
                            <span>not possible</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipDelay">
                            <span>Delay before redirect</span>
                            <span>
                                10 seconds (or more, depending on your settings)<br/>
                                (redirect also happens when user clicks on 'proceed')
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="pricing">Price : free (for ever!)</h3>
                </div>
                
                <div class="offer">
                    <div class="offerBefore"></div>
                    <div class="offerTitle">
                        <h3>Member</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="conditions">
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipLinks">
                            <span>Links</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipRedirects">
                            <span>Redirects</span>
                            <span>two-hundred-thousand (max, per month)<br/>(you'll be notified per e-mail when you risk losing clicks)</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipChange">
                            <span>Change the url redirected</span>
                            <span>to any url</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipCustom">
                            <span>Custom links / branding</span>
                            <span>10 max</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipDelay">
                            <span>Delay before redirect</span>
                            <span>
                                10 seconds (or more, depending on your settings)<br/>
                                (redirect also happens when user clicks on 'proceed')
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="pricing">Price : 10 USD per month</h3>
                </div>
                
                <div class="offer">
                    <div class="offerBefore"></div>
                    <div class="offerTitle">
                        <h3>Basic</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="conditions">
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipLinks">
                            <span>Links</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipRedirects">
                            <span>Redirects</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipChange">
                            <span>Change the url redirected</span>
                            <span>to any url</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipCustom">
                            <span>Custom links / branding</span>
                            <span>20 max</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipDelay">
                            <span>Delay before redirect</span>
                            <span>
                                10 seconds (or more, depending on your settings)<br/>
                                (redirect also happens when user clicks on 'proceed')
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="pricing">Price : 20 USD per month</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="offer">
                    <div class="offerBefore"></div>
                    <div class="offerTitle">
                        <h3>Advanced</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="conditions">
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipLinks">
                            <span>Links</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipRedirects">
                            <span>Redirects</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipChange">
                            <span>Change the url redirected</span>
                            <span>to any url</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipCustom">
                            <span>Custom links / branding</span>
                            <span>100 max</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipDelay">
                            <span>Delay before redirect</span>
                            <span>
                                5 seconds (or more, depending on your settings)<br/>
                                (redirect also happens when user clicks on 'proceed')
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="pricing">Price : 50 USD per month</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="offer">
                    <div class="offerBefore"></div>
                    <div class="offerTitle">
                        <h3>Enterprise</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="conditions">
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipLinks">
                            <span>Links</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipRedirects">
                            <span>Redirects</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipChange">
                            <span>Change the url redirected</span>
                            <span>to any url</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipCustom">
                            <span>Custom links / branding</span>
                            <span>Unlimited</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="tooltip siteMainTooltipsterTheme tooltipDelay">
                            <span>Delay before redirect</span>
                            <span>
                                2 seconds (or more, depending on your settings)<br/>
                                (redirect also happens when user clicks on 'proceed')
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="pricing">Price : 100 USD per month</h3>
                </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.tooltipLinks').each(function(idx,el){
                    el.title = 'Total number of URLs that can get translated for you by https://zoned.at';
                });
                $('.tooltipRedirects').each(function(idx,el){
                    el.title = 'Total number of times your URLs can get redirected to your chosen destination for such a URL.';
                });
                $('.tooltipChange').each(function(idx,el){
                    el.title = 'Whether or not (and if so, how) the URL redirected to can be changed.';
                });
                $('.tooltipCustom').each(function(idx,el){
                    el.title = 'Whether or not (and if so, how many) you can use https://zoned.at/yourBrandLink to point to a destination, instead of https://zoned.at/cjd8J';
                });
                $('.tooltipDelay').each(function(idx,el){
                    el.title = 'Whether or not (and if so, for how long) there will be a forced delay before the user is redirected to the destination.';
                });
                $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
                    theme : 'siteMainTooltipsterTheme',
                    animation : 'grow',
                    functionPosition: function(instance, helper, position) {
                    //debugger;
                        position.coord.left = $(helper.origin).offset().left;
                        position.coord.top = $(helper.origin).offset().top;
                        return position;
                    }
                });
                
                $('.offerBefore').each(function(idx,el){
                    $(el).css({ width : $(el).parent('div.offer').width(), height : $(el).parent('div.offer').height() });
                });
                $('div.offer').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).addClass('anim');
                });
                $('div.offer').hover(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('offer').addClass('offerHover');
                    
                }, function() {
                    $(this).addClass('offer').removeClass('offerHover');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div> <!-- class="flex-item" -->
    </div> <!-- class="row" -->
    </div> <!-- class="flex-container" -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
    html, body {
    height : 100%;
}
body {
    overflow : auto;
}
body[theme="dark"] {
    background : black url('dark-rock-wall-seamless-texture-free4.jpg') repeat;
    /* http://www.textures4photoshop.com/tex/stone-and-rock/dark-rock-wall-seamless-texture-free.aspx */
}
body[theme="light"] {
    background : white url('gray_background_for_websites.jpg') repeat;
    /* http://www.textures4photoshop.com/tex/stone-and-rock/dark-rock-wall-seamless-texture-free.aspx */
}
.flex-container {
    height : 100%;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index : 1;
}
.row {
    width : auto;
    margin : 20px;
    background : rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border : 1px solid black;
    border-radius : 33px;
    box-shadow : 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(102,255,102,0.5), 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index : 2;
}
.flex-item {
    margin : 18px;
    padding : 15px;
    z-index : 3;
}
.flex-title {
    padding : 10px;
    border : 1px solid black;
    border-radius : 18px;
    background : rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow : 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align : center;
}
h1, h2, .H2, h3 {
    color : white;
    text-shadow : 0px 0px 5px rgba(255,255,102,0.8), 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align : center;
}
h3 {
    color : lime;
}
h3.pricing {
    color : lightgreen;
}
div.content {
    width : auto;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    color : rgba(0,204,255,1);
    z-index : 1;
}

div.offer {
    z-index:1500000;
}

div.offerBefore {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}    

td.offer {
    z-index : 3;
}
div.offer {
    padding : 5px;
    font-weight : bold;
}
div.offerHover {
    padding : 5px;
    font-weight : bold;
}

div.offerBefore {
    margin-left : -10px;
    width : calc(100% + 20px);
}

div.conditions p span:nth-child(1) {
    float : left;
    width : 250px;
    height : 2rem;
}
div.conditions p span:nth-child(2) {
    float : right;
    width : calc(100% - 250px);
    height : 2rem;
}

td.offer > div.offerBefore {
    border : 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    box-shadow : inset -2px -2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0), 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

div.offerHover.anim > div.offerBefore {
    background : url("cloth 001B.png") repeat;
    color : black;
    animation-name : anim_pricingBlock_toHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius : 15px;
}
div.offer.anim > div.offerBefore {
    background : url("cloth 001B.png") repeat;
    color : black;
    animation-name : anim_pricingBlock_fromHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius : 15px;
}
@keyframes anim_pricingBlock_toHover {
    from { opacity : 0; border : 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
        box-shadow : inset -2px -2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0), 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    to { opacity : 1; border : 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1); 
        box-shadow : inset -2px -2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), inset 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
}
@keyframes anim_pricingBlock_fromHover {
    from { opacity : 1; border : 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
        box-shadow : inset -2px -2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), inset 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    to { opacity : 0; border : 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
        box-shadow : inset -2px -2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0), 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
}

table.content tr td:nth-child(2) {
    color : rgba(0,225,255,1);
}

div.offerHover.anim div.conditions {
    min-width : 700px;
    width : auto;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    color : rgba(0,204,255,1);
    animation-name : anim_pricingLeft_toHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
div.offer.anim div.conditions {
    min-width : 700px;
    width : auto;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    color : rgba(0,204,255,1);
    animation-name : anim_pricingLeft_fromHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes anim_pricingLeft_toHover {
    from { color : rgba(0,204,255,1);  }
    to { color : black;  }
}
@keyframes anim_pricingLeft_fromHover {
    from { color : black; }
    to { color : rgba(0,204,255,1); }
}
div.offerHover.anim div.conditions p span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-name : anim_pricingRight_toHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
div.offer.anim div.conditions p span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-name : anim_pricingRight_fromHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes anim_pricingRight_toHover {
    from { color : rgba(0,240,255,1); }
    to { color : black; }
}
@keyframes anim_pricingRight_fromHover {
    from { color : black; }
    to { color : rgba(0,240,255,1); }
}

.offerHover.anim h3 {
    animation-name : anim_pricingTitle_toHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}    
.offer.anim h3 {
    animation-name : anim_pricingTitle_fromHover;
    animation-duration : 2s;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}    
@keyframes anim_pricingTitle_toHover {
    from { color : lightgreen; }
    to { color : navy; }
}
@keyframes anim_pricingTitle_fromHover {
    from { color : navy; }
    to { color : lightgreen; }
}

.pricingCategory {
    font-size : 150%;
}
a {
    color : rgba(0,240,255,1);
}
a:hover {
    color : rgba(0,255,240,1);
}  
a:visited {
    color : rgba(0,255,200,1);
} 

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme .tooltipster-box {
    width : 120%;
    border-radius : 7px;
    border : 1px solid yellow;
    box-shadow : 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), 0px 0px 7px rgba(50,255,50,0.7);
    background : url('seamless_texture_of_ice.jpg') repeat;
    opacity : 1;
    color : black;
}
.siteMainTooltipsterTheme .tooltipster-content {
    color : black;
    font-family : Architects Daughter;
    font-size : 15px;
    padding : 8px 10px;
/* animation : siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim 2s infinite;*/
    border-radius : 7px;
}
/*
@keyframes siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim {
    0% {
        background : rgba(50,50,255,0)
    }
    50% {
        background : rgba(50,50,255,0.33)
    }
    100% { 
        background : rgba(50,50,255,0)
    }
}

@keyframes siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2a {
    0% {
        border-bottom-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
    50% {
        border-bottom-color : rgba(50,50,255,0.7)
    }
    100% { 
        border-bottom-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
}
@keyframes siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2b {
    0% {
        border-left-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
    50% {
        border-left-color : rgba(50,50,255,0.7)
    }
    100% { 
        border-left-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
}
@keyframes siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2c {
    0% {
        border-right-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
    50% {
        border-right-color : rgba(50,50,255,0.7)
    }
    100% { 
        border-right-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
}
@keyframes siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2d {
    0% {
        border-top-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
    50% {
        border-top-color : rgba(50,50,255,0.7)
    }
    100% { 
        border-top-color : rgba(255,255,255,0)
    }
}
*/


.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-background {
    /*border: 10px solid transparent;*/
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-background {
    border-bottom-color: white;
    /*animation : siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2a 2s infinite;*/
    left: 0;
    top: 3px;
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow-background {
    border-left-color: white;
    /*animation : siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2b 2s infinite;*/
    left: -3px;
    top: 0;
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-background {
    border-right-color: white;
    /*animation : siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2c 2s infinite;*/
    left: 3px;
    top: 0;
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow-background {
    border-top-color: white;
    /*animation : siteMainTooltipsterThemeAnim2d 2s infinite;*/
    left: 0;
    top: -3px;
}

/* .tooltipster-arrow-border */

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-border {
    /*border: 10px solid transparent;*/
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-border {
    border-bottom-color: yellow;
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow-border {
    border-left-color: yellow;
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-border {
    border-right-color: yellow;
}

.siteMainTooltipsterTheme.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow-border {
    border-top-color: yellow;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    
    border: 1px solid #012880;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #00FF00 0%, #00AA00 100%);
    box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1.25rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.50),
                            0 -0.25rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 80, 0, 1) inset,
                            0 0.75rem 0.5rem rgba(255,255,255, 0.4) inset,
                            0 0.25rem 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 80, 0, 1) inset;
}
button span {
    color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0000B0 0%, #0000FF 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 2px hsla(290, 100%, 20%, 1));
}
/*
button::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0.35rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.75rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    
    opacity: 0.35;
    filter : blur(2px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-270deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.00) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.00) 100%);
}
button:hover::before {
    animation : anim_buttonWhiteLines 2s infinite;
}*/
button::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0.25rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.75rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    
    filter: blur(1px);
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-270deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.00) 0%, #FFFFFF 20%, #FFFFFF 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.00) 100%);
}
button:hover::after {
    animation : anim_buttonWhiteLines 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes anim_buttonWhiteLines {
    0% {
        opacity : 0.35;
        filter : blur(2px);
    }
    50% {
        opacity : 0.7;
        filter : blur(0px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity : 0.35;
        filter : blur(2px);
    }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE : dropping the flex box declaration on the container div (the only 1 to have it), doesn't fix the problem. changing the <P> to <DIV> doesn't either. neither does changing the tooltip component to 'poshytip'.

Comment: UPDATE : dropping the use of a tooltip enhancement component all together, does work to fix the problem, but it's just not what i want.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer with some help from ##javascript on IRC..

```
div.conditions span:nth-child(1) {
    /*float : left;*/
    display : table-cell;
    width : 250px;
    height : 2rem;
}
div.conditions span:nth-child(2) {
    /*float : right;*/
    display : table-cell;
    width : calc(100% - 250px);
    height : 2rem;
}
```